# red parsing and replacing double % with <> doesn't work

Tags: parsing, rebol, red

I want to transform

```
 test: "bla bla %bla bla% bla bla bla bla %bla% bla"
```

into

```
 test: "bla bla <bla bla> bla bla bla bla <bla> bla"
```

with this code, it doesn't work in red:

```
 rules: [
    (toggle: -1)
    to "%" mark: (
        (toggle: 0 - toggle)
        either (toggle = 1) [change mark {<}][change mark {>}]
    )
    thru "%"
    |
    to end
]

parse test rules
```

Output is

```
>> test
== "bla bla <bla bla% bla bla bla bla %bla% bla"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your rules need a little more care, especially when using the keywords `'to` and `'thru`. The way your rule is written the replacement will occur once and then `to end` will advance you to the end of the input -- not what you want.

I'll step through it slowly.

The first rule, the  `to "%"`, this advances the input to the first "%" character. It's a successful rule so your parens expression executes and modifies the input, i.e., changes the "%" to a "<". All good there: the first replacement is complete and the very next char in the input is now "<". *BUT* your next rule is `thru "%"`. This advances the input *past* the next "%" character in the input-- a char you want changed to ">".

The other key piece here (as HostileFork points out) is that your replacement rule is not repeating. Your parse rule runs once and then it's over. Your alternative rule `to end` then takes over and jumps the input all way to the end.  In order to get a rule to scan repeatedly through the entire input you need to set up your rule with a `some`, `any`, `while` or `skip`.

Here's a quick rework of your rule leaving most of your code in place but achieving the result I think you want.

```
test: "bla bla %bla bla% bla bla bla bla %bla% bla"
toggle: -1
rules: [any [
    to "%" mark: (
        toggle: negate toggle 
        either toggle = 1 [change mark "<"][change mark ">"]
    ) 
    ]
]
parse test rules
test
 == "bla bla <bla bla> bla bla bla bla <bla> bla"
```

There are other things in the code that I would probably change, such as the  toggle, and you can see I got rid of unecessary parentheses, but for now I'm forcusing on the way `parse` works.

Answer (score 4):

You don't have any iterative construct in your parse rule (SOME, ANY, WHILE, etc.)  So it shouldn't be surprising it does one replacement and stops.

This will give you the desired output, and has a couple other changes for consideration (though just including the `any [... | skip]` modification would have fixed your code):

```
rules: [
    (toggle: true)
    any [
        to "%" mark: thru "%" (
            change mark pick [{>} {<}] (toggle: not toggle)
        )
    |
        skip
    ]
]

parse test rules
```

*(I'm not the biggest fan of using PICK with a LOGIC!...it gives you the first element if true and the second if false, but throwing it in here for fun.)*

Answer (score 2):

Two solutions: one without parse

```
test: "bla bla %bla bla% bla bla bla bla %bla% bla"
replace test "%" "<"
replace test "%" ">"
replace test "%" "<"
replace test "%" ">"
```

and one with parse

```
test: "bla bla %bla bla% bla bla bla bla %bla% bla"
parse test [some [to "%" change skip "<"  to "%" change skip ">"] to end]
```

and one for fun

```
parse test [(tog: next [">" "<"]) some [to "%" change skip tog  (reverse head tog)] to end]
```