# Parse looping forever when replacing %% by <!-- -->

Tags: parsing, rebol, red

I want to transform

```
 test: "bla bla %bla bla% bla bla bla bla %bla% bla"
```

into

```
 test: "bla bla <!--bla bla--> bla bla bla bla <!--bla--> bla"
```

which I thought would be easy as it was a slight variation of [red parsing and replacing double % with <> doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47036192/red-parsing-and-replacing-double-with-doesnt-work)

but my code loops forever though I have "to end" rule:

```
test: "bla bla %bla bla% bla bla bla bla %bla% bla"


toggle: -1
rules: [ 
    any [
        to "%" mark: (
            toggle: negate toggle 
            either toggle = 1 [change mark {} insert mark {<!--}][change mark {} 
            insert mark {-->}]
    ) 
    ]
    |
    to end
] 

parse test rules
test
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from you trying to exchange "%" with an empty string. "%" stays there and gets always a hit. Your rule works with these modifications

```
rules: [ 
    any [
        to "%" mark: (
            toggle: negate toggle 
            either toggle = 1 [
                change/part mark  {<!--} 1 
            ][
                change/part   mark {-->} 1
            ]
        ) 
    ] 
    to end
]
```

Answer (score 3):

I would not use `to` (or `thru`), they are bit dangerous IMO. I would use something like:

```
toggle: false 
parse test [
    some [
        change #"%" (either toggle: not toggle ["<!--"]["-->"]) 
    |   skip
    ]
]
```

Also, you can get rid of the `toggle`, if you want to:

```
parse test [
    some [
        change #"%" (first reverse ["-->" "<!--"]) 
    |   skip
    ]
]
```

Comment: Really smart solution :) Will use when I'll be more advanced, for now my purpose is learning the basics.

Comment: Ok :) But I think that you should adopt at least `logic!` toggle instead of `integer!` one. You can split it into two lines - `toggle: not toggle either toggle...` - like in your original code. `logic!` is more appropriate here, `toggle = 1` gets reduced into `logic!` anyway, so why not to use it directly.

Answer (score 2):

Without using `parse`, though there is no advantage, just another way:

```
until [none? attempt [insert remove find test "%" first reverse ["-->" "<!--"]]]
```